Upgrading an End of Life (lunar) installation
I finally got around to being able to try to upgrade by Ubuntu Lunar installation. Unfortunately, my experience upgrading to lunar was a pain at the time, so I kept putting it off.
I see that lunar is no longer supported by do-release-upgrade. Based on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades , I manually updated my sources.list to point to old-releases. Specifically:
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-updates main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-updates universe

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-updates multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security multiverse

This, however, returns 404s on apt update :
❯ sudo apt update
Ign:13 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease                                                                
Ign:17 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease                                                       
Ign:20 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease                                                      
Ign:22 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease                                                       
Err:23 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar Release                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:24 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates Release                                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:25 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports Release                                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:26 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security Release                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Reading package lists... Done                  

(Various lp ppas are other third party repositories not shown. I expect they'll cause their own issues, but I'll deal with them when I get to that point.)
I took a look at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ , and see that lunar does not seem to be here.
What options do I have to upgrade this lunar installation relatively safely? I've been using this particular install since focal and don't really want to try reinstalling, if possible.

It is way past EOL you need to do a whole new install, not an upgrade.

My mistake. 13.04. I originally thought I was on 12.10 and did not fully correct the number. The rest of it still holds, though.

If they haven't been moved to old-releases yet (which is done manually, not on a set schedule), then they'll still be in the main archive http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, and you can see lunar is present in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

Lunar is 23.04. And still outdated. Best to backup your data, /home, settings in /etc if you changed anything (I edit grub, but make copy in /home for backup). If you manually installed lots of apps export that list to make it easy to reinstall. Then do new install & restore from backup.

Ubuntu 23.04 had one upgrade path; which was to the next release being Ubuntu 23.10. That upgrade path was gone via official Ubuntu methods when 23.10 reached EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/).  Standard EOLUpgrades link is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but for desktops I just non-destructively re-install the release I want to upgrade to  (not useful for server apps & can be more complicated with 3rd party apps too)

I seem to have managed to work out the issue, though I do not know yet how much of my system is actually functional. I'm putting this here as an answer for the next person who comes looking.
The error message do-release-upgrade shows and the URL it refers you to does not exist. It redirects instead to https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle , which does not actually address the error or how it needs to be handled. The table of releases you can get to from here does, at this time, list lunar as End Of Life.
A separate search will get you to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades . This document might be out of date or does not adequately address the messages do-release-upgrade might emit. More importantly, the error messages do-release-upgrade produces are quite unhelpful.
Specifically, the document starts with assuming you need to go into old-releases. In this particular case, ie, lunar in July 2024, this is not necessary and will not actually work, as lunar repos are still on the regular archive. This is contradictory to the documentation suggesting it would need old-releases since it is explicitly EOL. So before you try switching to old-releases, manually verify where your release's repos are by checking http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ and http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/. If your release is already in old-releases, then update your sources.list accordingly as per the instructions.
In the same document, however, hidden away in "Unsupported upgrades", is the actual problem. Though not explicitly stated anywhere in these documents, do-release-upgrade cannot jump multiple versions, and do-release-upgrade tries to jump to the latest version irrespective of what the starting version is. The error message simply states it cannot upgrade from <installed codename> to <latest codename>, and provides no additional information about why. It does not suggest a multi-hop upgrade is required. The documentation says that multihop upgrades may sometimes be needed, but I suspect you will always need to do this.
In order to actually do the upgrade, you would need to follow the instructions in the section on Unsupported upgrades at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades . Specifically, for each intervening ubuntu release between where you are and where you want to be, you'd download the UpgradeTool from https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and execute it, one after the other.
When you do this, all the usual caveats for what you do when you apply major upgrades apply. My upgrade from lunar to mantic completely borked Grub, for example, and needed BootRepair to purge and reinstall grub. So you might want to have a liveUSB of some description handy when you try to do this. Also, backup all the data you care about, etc in case something breaks irrecoverably.
Note, however, that I'm not sure what would happen if your current release is in old-releases, and there are additional releases after yours which are in old-releases. If the first upgrade works you may need to update the sources.list once again when running the next upgrade. I am not sure whether the first upgrade would actually work or not, though, since the target repositories do not exist in the place they are expected to be found.
EDIT : Additional Notes
As on 24 Nov 24, mantic is in old releases, while lunar is still in archive. I expect there is someone, somewhere who understands why this is so.
The upgrade path needed is:
  lunar     -> mantic -> noble     -> oracular
  (releases)   (old)     (releases)   (releases)

The UpgradeTool for mantic breaks because it can't find the repositories in archive. The only way this seems to be solvable is to upgrade from lunar to mantic manually, ie, change the apt sources.list to point to the mantic repositories in old-releases and run upgrade and dist-upgrade. Other third-party respositories and PPAs (usually sources.list.d) are best disabled for this process. While you might get lucky, plan for significant breakage when trying to do this.
Once on mantic, do-release-upgrade or the UpgradeTool for noble should be able to get you to noble.

Thank you. I had the literal exact same problem.

Amazing. Thank you. This was the solution for me:

you'd download the UpgradeTool from https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and execute it, one after the other.

Since i'm on 13.04, which is EOL as well as the release the follows it (13.10), no other approaches worked, including pointing my apt repos to old-releases.

This is what worked for me > https://gist.github.com/catchsudheera/68bcb4747e7e4127cd1162112791c99e
